# Read a file to multiple byte arrays

Tags: java, file, file-io

I have an encryption algorithm (AES) that accepts a file converted to array byte and encrypt it. 
Since I am going to process a very large files, the JVM may go out of memory. 
I am planing to read the files in multiple byte arrays, each containing some part of the file. Then I iteratively feed the algorithm. Finally, I merge them to produce an encrypted file.

So my question is: Is there any way to read a file part by part to multiple byte arrays?

I thought I could use the following to read the file to a byte array:

```
    IOUtils.toByteArray(InputStream input).
```

And then split the array into multiple bytes using:

```
    Arrays.copyOfRange()
```

But I am afraid that the code that reads a file to `ByteArray` will make the JVM to go out of memory.

Comment: Most encryption algorithms work on blocks of data, and do not need the entire data at once.  This is to avoid exactly the problem you're talking about, where you need the entire plaintext in memory in order to compute ciphertext based on it.  Maybe just use the `read(byte[], int, int)` functions to read a block at a time and feed it to your algorithm.

Comment: Look up cipher streams in Java. You can use them to encrypt/decrypt streams on the fly so you don't have to store the whole thing in memory. All you have to do then is copy the regular `FileInputStream` for your source file to the `CipherOutputStream` that's wrapping your `FileOutputStream` for the encrypted sink file. `IOUtils` even conveniently contains a `copy(InputStream, OutputStream)` method to do this copy for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look up cipher streams in Java. You can use them to encrypt/decrypt streams on the fly so you don't have to store the whole thing in memory. All you have to do is copy the regular `FileInputStream` for your source file to the `CipherOutputStream` that's wrapping your `FileOutputStream` for the encrypted sink file. `IOUtils` even conveniently contains a `copy(InputStream, OutputStream)` method to do this copy for you.

For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    encryptFile("exampleInput.txt", "exampleOutput.txt");
}

public static void encryptFile(String source, String sink) {
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(source);
        CipherOutputStream cos = null;
        try {
            cos = new CipherOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(sink), getEncryptionCipher());
            IOUtils.copy(fis, cos);
        } finally {
            if (cos != null)
                cos.close();
        }
    } finally {
        if (fis != null)
            fis.close();
    }
}

private static Cipher getEncryptionCipher() {
    // Create AES cipher with whatever padding and other properties you want
    Cipher cipher = ... ;
    // Create AES secret key
    Key key = ... ;
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
}
```

If you need to know the number of bytes that were copied, you can use `IOUtils.copyLarge` instead of `IOUtils.copy` if the file sizes exceed `Integer.MAX_VALUE` bytes (2 GB).

To decrypt the file, do the same thing, but use `CipherInputStream` *instead of*`CipherOutputStream` and initialize your `Cipher` using `Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE`.

Take a look [here](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/security/ch13_06.htm) for more info on cipher streams in Java.

This will save you space because you won't need to store `byte` arrays of your own anymore. The only stored `byte[]` in this system is the internal `byte[]` of the `Cipher`, which will get cleared each time enough input is entered and an encrypted block is returned by `Cipher.update`, or on `Cipher.doFinal` when the `CipherOutputStream` is closed. However, you don't have to worry about *any* of this since it's all internal and everything is managed for you.

**Edit:** note that this can result in certain encryption exceptions being ignored, particularly `BadPaddingException` and `IllegalBlockSizeException`. This behavior can be found in the [`CipherOutputStream` source code](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/javax/crypto/CipherOutputStream.java.html). (Granted, this source is from the OpenJDK, but it probably does the same thing in the Sun JDK.) Also, from the [CipherOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/crypto/CipherOutputStream.html) javadocs:

> This class adheres strictly to the semantics, especially the failure semantics, of its ancestor classes `java.io.OutputStream` and `java.io.FilterOutputStream`. This class has exactly those methods specified in its ancestor classes, and overrides them all. **Moreover, this class catches all exceptions that are not thrown by its ancestor classes.**

The bolded line here implies that the cryptographic exceptions are ignored, which they are. This may cause some unexpected behavior while trying to read an encrypted file, especially for block and/or padding encryption algorithms like AES. Make a mental note of this that you will get zero or partial output for the encrypted (or decrypted for `CipherInputStream`) file.

Comment: The Java cipher streams may shove exceptions, especially `BadPaddingException`s under the table. You've been warned.

Comment: Eek, that it will. I'll update my answer with that information.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `IOUtils`, perhaps you should consider [IOUtils.copyLarge()](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#copyLarge%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream,%20long,%20long%29)

```
public static long copyLarge(InputStream input,
                             OutputStream output,
                             long inputOffset,
                             long length)
```

and specify a [ByteArrayOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) as the output. You can then iterate through and load sections of your file using offset/length.

From the doc:

> Copy some or all bytes from a large (over 2GB) InputStream to an
>   OutputStream, optionally skipping input bytes.

Comment: how does that help memory usage if you are copying into a ByteArrayOutputStream?

Comment: Because you only copy portions at a time. I would have thought that was obvious, but I will amend

Comment: Hmm, I don't see why this is required. You may use buffered streams instead, although most of the time disk I/O is buffered anyway, so it won't matter too much.

Comment: maybe you didn't understand my comment.  why does copying portions of the file at a time matter when you are putting the entire file into a ByteArrayOutputStream, i.e. "one giant byte array"?  (in other words, your ByteArrayOutputStream is going to be causing memory problems).

Comment: @jtahlborn If I'm not mistaken, what he's advocating is copying a section of the file to the BAOS via offset/length, getting the bytes from the BAOS, encrypting them, and writing the encrypted bytes to the sink output stream, then doing the whole process over with a clean BAOS. Remember that you can reset a BAOS and limit its buffer size. At this point though, you may as well just use a vanilla `byte[]` and the input stream's `int read(byte[])` method and skip the BAOS altogether.

Comment: @Brian - ah, now i see where the example is going.  i didn't realize the BAOS was only holding part of the file at a time.  yeah, don't really see the point of the BAOS instead of a `byte[]` if you are just copying chunks (bunch of superfluous array copying).